# HtmlHelper inside Razor "if" statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have written an HtmlHelper Extension to format some content based some of our styles. **The helpers render the content correctly when not enclosed within an if.**

However, when I am trying to wrap them in a razor if statement, nothing is rendering, I suspect it has something to do with the Razor syntax that I am not doing correctly.

Code:

```
<div class="notice">

    @if (DataModel.UserHasExpired)
    {
       Html.MyCustomNotificationBox("someparameter") // My helper Should render a div
    }

</div>
```

If I place my notificationbox outside of the if, it works fine. I have also verified that the code is dropping into the block, but none of the markup is generated in the html when I inspect it.

I've tried appening a @ like so, and ending with a colon

```
@Html.MyCustomNotificationBox("somparameter");
```

I have even tried @Html.Raw(..with the above..) which completely errors out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might help if you included the code for your helper.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried putting it in `text` tags (those tags are not sending to client)?

```
@if (DataModel.UserHasExpired)
{
    <text>@Html.MyCustomNotificationBox("somparameter")</text>
}
```

Comment: In this case, the <text> tag might be appropriate, but using the '@' symbol seems more native.

Answer (score 8):

```
<p>
   @if (true)
   {
       @Html.Hello("World")
   }
</p>
```

Works Perfectly fine

Comment: I like this better because it avoids a custom <text> tag